# populating dropdown using innerhtml

Tags: javascript

I am developing a autocomplete textbox which displays search results in the form of dropdown below the text box.

```
document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = response
```

The above line populates dropdown with values in **Firefox** but in **IE** dropdown is displaying no result.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: What you use for drop-down? Select input/custom UI widget/simple div?

Comment: alert(response) and post the result

Comment: <INPUT TYPE="text"   
             NAME="textInput"  
             SIZE=18   
             AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF"  
             ONKEYDOWN="combotext_onkeydown(event, this, this.form.selectInput)" onKeyUp="getRequest('ajax.jsp?id='+this.value,'mySelect','loading.gif',event);" >

Comment: <span id="useeme">
      <SELECT NAME="selectInput"  id="mySelect" SIZE=8 
    STYLE="display:none; position:absolute; top:20px; left:0px;width:auto;"   
             ONBLUR="this.style.display='none'"  
             ONCHANGE="comboselect_onchange(this, this.form.textInput)"  
             ONKEYUP="comboselect_onkeyup(event.keyCode, this, this.form.textInput)">        
      </SELECT>  
   </span>

Comment: remove display:none;  from select tag and then try

Comment: change this getRequest('ajax.jsp?id='+this.value,'useeme','loading.gif',event);

Comment: function getRequest(url,id,msg,ee){

/*if(ee.keyCode == 40 || ee.keyCode==38)
 {
 //var sel = $("li[class='selected']");
    alert("up-down");
 }
 else{ */
 elementId=id;
 loadingMesg=msg; 
 http.open('get', url);
 
 /* Define a function to call once a response has been received. This will be our
  handleProductCategories function that we define below. */
 http.onreadystatechange = ManipulateRequest;
 /* Send the data. We use something other than null when we are sending using the POST
  method. */
 http.send(null);
 //}
}

Comment: function ManipulateRequest(){
 if(loadingMesg=="") var msg="Please wait... loading";
  else msg="<img src='"+ loadingMesg + "' alt='lodding' />";    //loadingMesg;
 if(http.readyState == 1)
 {
  document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = msg;
 }
 else if(http.readyState == 4){ //Finished loading the response
  var response = http.responseText ;
  if(response.length < 34){   
        document.getElementById("useeme").style.display = "none";
   }else{
  
          document.getElementById("useeme").style.display = "block";   
 } 
  document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = response;
 }
}

Comment: This code is working in ie 10 but not in ie 9

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the span Id as element id

change this `getRequest('ajax.jsp?id='+this.value,'useeme','loading.gif',event);`